# How to change text of an html button with jquery

Tags: jquery

I've watched a bunch of code ,none worked , and i am probably missing something . The only thing that worked for me in jquery and javascript was document.write . I don't know if there's something wrong with the code , or if i have to include something

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#klik').click(function() {

        $('#klik').text('test');

    }); 
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<button id="klik">Click me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In a comment on a deleted answer, you asked "why onload is required when i need the event to fire when the button is clicked?" The problem isn't the click, it's *hooking up* the click to the element. When you do `$("#klik").click(...);`, the first part -- `$("#klik")` -- looks up the element with that ID in the DOM. But because your script is *before* you define that element, it doesn't exist yet, so the handler isn't attached to anything, and so the code in it never runs. If you just move your code *after* you've defined the element (my recommendation) or or use `ready` (Neal's), it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include jquery before you use it and also the dom didn't have the button when you try to access it

Working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/p3LuH/

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<button id="klik">Click me!</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#klik').click(function() {

            $('#klik').text('test');

        }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script code has to be below the declaration of the element itself? I just thought that order doesn't matter...

Comment: Yes. You need to understand what this code does :: $('#klik').click(function...{}) --> It finds the element klik and attaches the click listener (function...{}) to it.

Comment: @user2227494: *"The script code has to be below the declaration of the element itself? I just thought that order doesn't matter.."* The order matters a great deal, because the element has to *exist* for you to hook up a handler to it. See my answer for details and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when your code runs, there is no DOM element with the ID `klik`. So your code attaching an event handler to it doesn't do anything.

If you just move your `script` element *underneath* where you define that element (and underneath where you include jQuery, since you're relying on jQuery being loaded), it will work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button id="klik">Click me!</button>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Since this doesn't run until the element exists, it works
    $('#klik').click(function() {

        $('#klik').text('test');

    }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternately, if you prefer, you can use the `ready` event, which isn't fired until all of the DOM elements in the HTML have been created:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { // <== This sets up a handler for the `ready` event

        // Since this doesn't run until the `ready` fires, the element exists, and it works
        $('#klik').click(function() {

            $('#klik').text('test');

        }); 

    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="klik">Click me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Barring a really good reason to use `ready`, it's best to put the `script` at the end of the `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag, so it's after all the elements you might operate on (and doesn't slow down the perceived load of your page).

References:

- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google Closure Library Engineers on when DOM Elements Are Available to script](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)